# Bootstrap 4 external style sheet Font Attributes won't work

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've been struggling to create my 1st website in years. Using bootstrap in Dreamweaver.

There is a steep learning curve, made worse because it seems like bootstrap just wants to do what it wants to do.

I want to set up my styles, H1, H2, etc...

So, I added the H1 style like so:

```
    h1 {
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", 
"sans-serif";
    font-size: 8em;
    text-align: left
}
```

And at first it looks like it works, but as soon as I move to do something else, or check in on my test page, it does back to whatever size it defaulted to.

Preceding it is this:

```
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

article, aside, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica 
Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe 
UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #0A0A0A;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

I have piece by piece removed each of this attributes to see what my be over-riding my H1 code, but it makes no difference.

What am I missing?

Experimenting with the rest of the standard styles, h2 through h6 have the same problem. I think P is retaining size but it won't get lighter.

[image: screenshot of what I'm seeing]

Mind you, the font family assigned to H1 stays. Whatever 4em, 8em, 30em, 100%, 300%, 600%.... That change will not present itself on a refresh of my test page and it will disappear from the Dreamweaver split view.

Thanks in advance.

Update: for @Isherwood

It only displays correctly within the Dreamweaver split screen interface as I change the CSS external sheet.

All this is new to me. It has been more than 8 years since I've built a site from scratch and I've only been member here for a few days.

I am quite the novice. I'm not even sure what you mean by "override styles".
I simply set h1, h2, h3, etc... in the HTML body portion around the text I want effected. I declare the font family, size, etc... in the external css as shown above.

But give me a while to see if I can figure out how to make a snippet as you requested.

Meanwhile, I do have this loaded online to see if that made any difference, in a folder on my husband's site.

https://www.walterbeckham.com/testingzone/one.html

Comment: It doesn't make sense that styles would be applied and then not. How are you loading your override styles? Please create a snippet demo with a bit of HTML using the editor. You can load Bootstrap via [CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) and put your CSS in the respective panel.

Comment: Isherwood, it occurred to me that Dreamweaver may have a functionality that predicts what should be displayed??
It only displays correctly within the Dreamweaver split screen interface as I change the CSS external sheet.

All this is new to me. It has been more than 8 years since I've built a site from scratch and I've only been member here for a few days. 

But give me a few minutes to see if I can figure out how to make a snippet as you requested.